# Python Selenium DOM Click event does not work as intended

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, dom

I am trying to click the pagination links (next button).  However the click goes to the site homepage. I am targeting the element by class.  What could be wrong ?

```
driver.get('https://www.marinetraffic.com/en/data/?asset_type=vessels&columns=flag,shipname,photo,recognized_next_port,reported_eta,reported_destination,current_port,imo,ship_type,show_on_live_map,time_of_latest_position,lat_of_latest_position,lon_of_latest_position&current_port_in|begins|FUJAIRAH%20ANCH|current_port_in=20585')

# Wait 30 seconds for page to load
timeout = 30
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'MuiButtonBase-root-60')))
    element = driver.find_element_by_class_name('MuiButtonBase-root-60')
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)


except TimeoutException:
    print("Timed out waiting for page to load")


driver.quit()
```

Comment: Please add the html of the element you are trying to click on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use Following Code :**

```
driver.get('https://www.marinetraffic.com/en/data/?

asset_type=vessels&columns=flag,shipname,photo,recognized_next_port,reported_eta,reported_destination,current_port,imo,ship_type,show_on_live_map,time_of_latest_position,lat_of_latest_position,lon_of_latest_position&current_port_in|begins|FUJAIRAH%20ANCH|current_port_in=20585')

# Wait 30 seconds for page to load
timeout = 30
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//p[text()='Page']//..//following-sibling::button")))  
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)

except TimeoutException:
    print("Timed out waiting for page to load")


driver.quit()
```

Comment: Thank you.  It worked..  Do you used any tool to copy the XPATH of an element ?  When I use chrome Dev Tool.  I get something like this.

`//*[@id="reporting_ag_grid"]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div[3]/button[2]`

Comment: @NoushadMoidunny : give me your gmail id

Comment: @NoushadMoidunny : Will help you on hangout call

Answer (score 1):

There are 33 elements with this class, `find_element_by_class_name` returns the first one, (which is located in the header). You can use the footer as starting point to narrow down the options and select the second button using index (there is no difference between the next and previous when both of the are available)

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.r-mtGridFooter-302 button:nth-of-type(2)')))
element.click()
```